# С помощью Notepad++ удалить код внутри фигурных скобок { }

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++, replace, find

[image: https://i.imgur.com/tBaRIqL.png]

```
addOns[]=
    {
        "A3_Misc_F_Helpers",
        "a3_map_altis",
        "task_force_radio_items",
        "a3_data_f_exp",
        "lop_faction_ists_c"
    };
    addOnsAuto[]=
    {
        "rhsusf_c_troops",
        "a3_data_f_exp"
    };
```

Как превратить данный код в

```
addOns[]=
    {

    };
    addOnsAuto[]=
    {

    };
```

Подсказали такой синтаксис, но Find what код неверный, выдает Invalid regular expression

```
   Find what:  addOns\[\] = {.*};
Replace with:  addOns[] = { };
Regular expressions, match newline
```

Вот исходник текста https://pastebin.com/eJjN5w28

Comment: Доброе утро. В sublime text вот так \".+\",?  В notepad+ должно быть так же.

Comment: Честно первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь, можете пожалуйста написать полностью что нужно писать в поле "Find what:" ?

Comment: Так и пишите, как я написал -  \".+\",?

Comment: Начинает правильно с addons{   , только уходит вниз до конца всего файла. Только addOns[]={ }; и addOnsAuto[]={ }; в 900+ файлах надо отчистить

Comment: Надо было сразу показывать полностью содержимое файла. Снимите "галочку" на matches native и нажмите replace all

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, в будущем буду лучше строить вопрос :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте найти

```
addOns\[\]\s*=[\s\r\n]*\{[\s\S\n\r]*?\}
```

Вероятно редактор применяет регулярки с ограничением по строкам. Чтобы обойти ограничение использовал символы `\r` и `\n`.

Comment: Invalid regular expression пишет, не хочет что-то. @Visman вот исходник, может так легче будет? https://pastebin.com/eJjN5w28

Comment: @abudabi, фигурные скобки тоже оказывается в Notepad++ экранировать надо. Изменил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло!